# Google's Geocode API get remaining quota balance

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I am looking at geocoding a bunch of items that we get in a queue every day. We have a google business account that allows us 100K geogcodes per day. Some days we get 10K addresses, other days we get 200K+, I am curious if there is a way programmatically to find out how many remaining geocode cals are available before we go over 100K, like "you have already geocoded 80K addresses today" so I know not to stick 70K more in the queue for that day.I can see in the google console how many I have remaining but want my script to be able to look it up. None of my searches have yielded anything useful on how to get this number. (Also, I don't want to cap my limit and just stop geocoding when I reach 100K) Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps Geocoding API usage limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290759/google-maps-geocoding-api-usage-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to check remaining quota programmatically. The feature request for this was filed in Google issue tracker some time ago. You can see it here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830575

I would suggest to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

I'm adding the link to this question to the feature request as well.