# Google Maps Geocoding API usage limit

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoding-api

I'm currently using Google's Maps Geocoding API and, as the documentation informs, it has a limit per day usage of 2500 requests.

Is there some service that I can call to check how many requests I already did, or I still can do? I know that in the Google's API Console has this information, but I was considering doing something programmatically with my application, where it can by itself know the current status and inform me if the request is close to ending.

FYI: I am aware that if the requests ended the service returns a flag informing OVER_QUOTA, but I'm interested in discovering before it has finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no any service that allows to check the usage programmatically.

The corresponding feature request has already been filed in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830575

Please add a star to the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to notifications from Google.